# I want the msgBox to show the cell's defined name instead of the cell address in 2010

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I am using the code below to validate that cells have information prior to saving a workbook.  The program works fine but is displaying the cells address ($P$14).  I want it to show the cells defined name (CompanyName).

```
For Each myRange In .Range("P14,P20,P23,P26,P29,P32,P33,P39")

    If myRange.Value = 0 And myRange.Offset(0, 0) = "" Then

        MsgBox ("You must make an entry in ") & myRange.Offset(0, 0).Address

        Cancel = True

    End If

Next myRange
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by Cell's defined name the 1st Row (ie "A1", "B1", etc) in the column where you added text (such as "Company Name" you mention) you can do this:
`Target.Worksheet.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value`
If you mean the particular Cell's "given name", ie renamed from (e.g.) "A1" to "uncleFOO", then you have to refer to 
`[object].Name.Name`
For example, `myRange.Offset(0, 0).Name.Name`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!  Your second option is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Could you please accept my feedback then as the answer? I get points if you mark it (which is silly but I like it :). Thanks in advance!